# App crash when launching from Xcode if app already installed on device through Testflight

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, testflight

I'm building an iOS app for which I have Testflight set up, but now I'm running into an interesting issue where I can't properly launch the app from Xcode anymore since I registered my device to test the app through Testflight.

When I try to launch the app from Xcode, it will build fine and even launch it on my phone. However, there will be no output in the console, and a few seconds later the app will crash on my phone and I get the following error message popup in Xcode:

> process launch failed: failed to get the task for process 484

If I delete the app from my phone before trying to launch from Xcode, the same thing will happen and the Testflight orange dot will still show up next to the app name on the home screen.

I have tried to change the app's version and build number, but that had no effect. I have not yet tried to unregister my device to test the app through Testflight because I would like to find a good way that facilitates both.

One way I have found to circumvent this problem is create a different app target and run the app with that which seems to work -- but I'm wondering if there is an actual solution to this problem or a better way to work around it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you remove your distribution cert from build settings?

Comment: Looks like you were thinking along the right lines. I posted an answer based on your comment -- thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Max was on the right track - if I manually specify a non-distribution provisioning profile it will work properly by overriding the Testflight version of the app (the orange dot disappears). Not sure why "automatic" wasn't doing that for me. Thank you!